# How can I get all documents that match my query in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to get all books that match my several book_ids, but instead I only get one of the books.

```
books =  mydb.Book.find({"book_id ": book_id})
```

Comment: you can set the variable that contains several book_ids and with a for loop you can apply `mydb.Book.find({"book_id ": book_id})` and append it another list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` to find all the documents that match any value in your list `book_ids`

see the [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
books =  mydb.Book.find({"book_id": {"$in": book_ids}})
```

Comment: Hi, now, I am getting this error: $in needs an array

Comment: You say in your question that you have "several book_ids". So I assumed that you had a list of ids named book_ids. Can you edit your question and more of your code to get context ?

Comment: I can read and print the IDs, but how can I push them into an array or list in python, I tried 'append', and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,
listBooks=[]
listBooks.append(book_id)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).